# Get firestore data when document id is equal to current logged user id in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, userid

I want to show a user profile section after the user login and enter the profile view section. In the authentication part, I store user data in cloud firestore database. on there I set document id equal to user id. Now I want to retrieve document field data by according to user id.

This is what I have done,

```
class MyProfile extends StatefulWidget {

Future<String> getData() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    final String uid = user.uid.toString();
    return uid;
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('My Profile'),
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF4A184C),
            ),
            body: 
            StreamBuilder(
             stream: 
             Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document().snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                if(!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading Data.. Please Wait...');
               return  
                Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(
                        Icons.account_circle,
                        size: 40,
                        color: Colors.amber,
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        "Name : " + snapshot.data['username'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                            color: Color(0xFF4A184C),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
.....
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have control over the creation of documents in `Users`, you can give them the same id as the `FirebaseUser`'s uid.

You can choose to use a `StreamBuilder` or a `FutureBuilder` to retrieve it.

If you want to have continuous updates on this data with a `StreamBuilder` you can use an async generator function.

```
Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getUserStream() async* {
  final uid = await getData();
  yield* Firestore.instance.document("Users/$uid").snapshots();
}
```

or if you rather just get the data only once, you can use a `FutureBuilder`. The future can be derived from the following function

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot> getUser() async {
  final uid = await getData();
  return Firestore.instance.document("Users/$uid").get();
}
```